# Amazon EC2 Instancia m5.large

Tags: webservice, cloud, ec2, amazon

Quisiera saber el significado de cada uno de los conceptos que aparecen en el encabezado. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación:

- [ECU es](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it) una unidad de medida relativa para el poder de cómputo asignado a una instancia. Como ves en tu captura de pantalla, no siempre se indica de acuerdo a la configuración de la instancia.

  > Amazon EC2 uses a variety of measures to provide each instance with a consistent and predictable amount of CPU capacity. In order to make it easy for developers to compare CPU capacity between different instance types, we have defined an Amazon EC2 Compute Unit. The amount of CPU that is allocated to a particular instance is expressed in terms of these EC2 Compute Units. We use several benchmarks and tests to manage the consistency and predictability of the performance from an EC2 Compute Unit. One EC2 Compute Unit provides the equivalent CPU capacity of a 1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor. This is also the equivalent to an early-2006 1.7 GHz Xeon processor referenced in our original documentation. Over time, we may add or substitute measures that go into the definition of an EC2 Compute Unit, if we find metrics that will give you a clearer picture of compute capacity
- *Memoria* es la cantidad de RAM asignada a la instancia.
- *Almacenamiento de instancias* corresponde a la estrategia a usar para la persistencia de datos en disco (porque es posible almacenar los datos en un disco separado de la instancia EC2). El que ofrecen en el tipo de instancias que tienes disponibles en la imagen es [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/), que es un bloque de almacenamiento "de alto rendimiento" para nodos con un throughput alto.